# What are the sentence/ idioms and phrases often used in day to day life? Are there any good articles available listing these items?

Tags: phrases, idioms, sentence

English speakers most often use simple phrases in their day to day life. It would be helpful for speaking easily if those sentences or phrases are known and you can share any link to learn those words.

Comment: I think the Idea is a bit naive. You woud get a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can download this [pdf file](http://www.easypacelearning.com/english-books/list-of-idioms-a-z-english-phrases/433-list-if-idioms-a-to-z-with-examples-and-meanings-english-phrases) which is a comprehensive list of English Languange idioms. It has sample sentences and provides historical information about most of the idioms therein.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android, get the app known as 'English Idioms' by 'Kreatorz'.
[This one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kreatorz.englishidioms.free)